# Specifying a start point of draggable div

Tags: html, css

I have a draggable div with `position: absolute;` and I'm trying to set it's start inside the center of another div.

```
<div id="all">
        <div class="move">
            <header>
                <h1>box</h1>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've set the `position` on `#all` to `relative`, which as far as my understanding should put the draggable div, `.move`, inside of it, but that isn't happening.

here is my css:

```
#all {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.move {
    cursor: move;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I've tried different ways to get the div to start at the horizontal center of the page too but to no avail.

```
header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And I don't think this is the cause of the problem but I'm including this bit of my css anyway.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` have to work with `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` in the same element.

I believe you want to center the `.move` horizontally. The below code should do it.

```css
#all {
  position: relative;
}

.move {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Please also note that you don't need both `left` and `right` to place an element.